# Are there any performance differences between multiple inheritance vs. multiple import statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Following scenario: Assuming I would have a `toolbox` package, which is set up like this e.g.

```
toolbox/
__init__.py
io/
    __init__.py
    input.py         # Contains DataInput class with method read_txt_file()
    output.py        # Contains DataOutput class
functionalities/
    __init__.py
    func1.py     # Contains class Func1 with method calculate()
    func2.py     # Contains class Func2
```

Each `*.py` file would contain a class, where multiple methods are defined within. This would have to be used as toolbox for multiple scripts/programs which only need some of the functionalities defined in there (e.g. Script A needs methods from class `DataInput` and class `Func1`, while Script B needs methods from class `DataOutput` and class `Func2`, etc...)

There would be now two possibilities to gather the desired methods (in this scenario methods `read_txt_file()` and `calculate()`):

1) Import the classes from the modules

```
from toolbox.io.input import DataInput
from toolbox.io.functionalities.func1 import Func1

obj1 = DataInput()
obj1.read_txt_file()
obj = Func1()
obj.get_data(obj1)           # Some getter method defined in Func1
obj.calculate()
```

2) Defining a class with multiple inheritance from classes `DataInput` and `Func1` such that an instance of this has the methods already inherited

```
import toolbox.io.input
import toolbox.functionalities.func1

class MyClass(toolbox.io.input.DataInput, toolbox.io.functionalities.func1.Func1):
    pass

obj = MyClass()
obj.read_txt_file()
obj.calculate()
```

In both cases the data from the textfile has been read, calculated and is now encapsulated in `obj`.

**The question is: What possibility would be the preferred one in terms of performance (runtime, memory, etc)?**

Footnote: I do know that data encapsulation and getter/setter methods are discussed controversely by Pythonistas. Although, I am interested in an evaluation of both possibilities.